# Without initialising a vector in a struct, will it automatically be empty or will it have a random memory location's values?

Tags: c++, variables, memory, vector, struct

I have some structs with vectors in them. I've assigned other variables in the struct with values, but I haven't referred to the vector at all.

When referring to my vector contained within the struct later in my program, will it be an empty vector or will it be assigned some random values based on whatever is in my computer's memory at that location?

I've tested the vector size out in debug mode and it has returned zero (i.e. empty vector) but I can't tell if that just happened to be the case or if it will always be empty.

Thanks!

Comment: Default constructed `vector` is empty. If you don't construct the `vector`, you `malloc` it  for example, you don't really have a `vector`, just a `vector` sized blob of memory.

Comment: It would be better if you code your statements after all this ain't theory class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The vectors in an instance of your struct will be constructed using the default constructor. The [default constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector) for a vector constructs a vector of size `0`